# Access JSON data from URL in PHP

Tags: php, json, url

I have a URL:

> localhost/index.php?a=something&jsondata={"error":"ok","result":{"amount":"100"}}

The above link is reached from another page by:

```
    $jsondata=json_encode($jsondata);
    header('Location:index.php?a=something&jsondata='.$jsondata.'');
```

Now I want to access the JSON data, and I used the below method to get the data:

```
    $result=$_REQUEST['jsondata'];
    $result=json_decode($result, true);
```

And to read the data in PHP, the below:

```
<?php echo $result['result']['amount']; ?>
```

But it is not showing any result.

It is just empty.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldnt it be urlencoded or something?

Comment: I am just learning, so any help is appreciated. Can you please ellaborate @frz3993

Comment: Some characters need to be urlencoded when is used in a url, because they represent special meaning in the url context. Typically can be divided to reserved characters, unsafe characters and unreserved. Example, the colon is used to define the port part of the host url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @frz3993 I was able to solve the issue

While sending the URL request:

```
$jsondata=json_encode($jsondata);
$jsondata=urlencode($jsondata);
header('Location:index.php?a=something&jsondata='.$jsondata.'');
```

While receiving the data in another page:

```
$result=$_REQUEST['jsondata'];
$result=urldecode($result);
$result=json_decode($result, true);
```

Then it can be read using:

```
<?php echo $result['result']['amount']; ?>
```